# Wordpress Jetpack sharing buttons displaying funny on custom theme

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I currently have a custom themed blog running on wordpress with Jetpack installed.

I have enabled Sharing, and have dragged various social site sharing services into the "Enabled Settings" section (Facebook, Twitter, Google+, Digg, etc).

However, on my custom blog the sharing buttons are presented in a listed order without any sharing icons (just text).

Which means my sharing bar looks like this:

```
A Blog Post
DD/MM/YY

blah blah blah blah blah

> Facebook
> Twitter
> (This is empty, its supposed to be Google+ here)
> Digg
> Etc

Posted in Uncategorized
```

Does anyone know the default CSS to display these sharing icons in Jetpack, or am i doing something wrong?

Comment: Sharing options, are they in any HTML structure, as a list?

Comment: Yes, they are in <li> format. i don't know if its a <ul> <li> thing though.

Comment: Attempts to examine the source code to make sure. I recommend the Firefox Web Developer plugin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right, turns out I left out a very important line of code to enable the plugins to work.

```
<?php wp_footer(); ?>
```

This has to be included immediately before the `</body>` tag in order for it to work.

I didn't include it in, and therefore it broke the plugin system, rendering any plugins that I've enabled to be useless.

Once you've got that in the right place, Jetpack should show up clearly and you only need minor tweaking (font size, margins, etc) to assimilate it into Wordpress.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

For example ( http://css.maxdesign.com.au/listamatic/horizontal02.htm):

```
HTML

<div id="navcontainer">
<ul id="navlist">
<li id="active"><a href="#" id="current">Item one</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Item two</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Item three</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Item four</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Item five</a></li>
</ul>
</div>

CSS
ul#navlist
{
margin-left: 0;
padding-left: 0;
white-space: nowrap;
}

#navlist li
{
display: inline;
list-style-type: none;
}

#navlist a { padding: 3px 10px; }

#navlist a:link, #navlist a:visited
{
color: #fff;
background-color: #036;
text-decoration: none;
}

#navlist a:hover
{
color: #fff;
background-color: #369;
text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: Yes, i've tried that, but the images arent showing. Especially the Gogole+ one, there's supposed to be a G+ icon and the number of people who have shared the post.

Comment: Attempts to modify the CSS (expand the width or height of the area) to check if the images exist.

Comment: Didn't work. Jetpack is supposed to customize it right away for you, without any huge amounts of tweaking, like i've learnt in the answer.